# Rails 4: Method that only shows records in the next 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have a model called Reminders with a column called Start (datetime).

How do I only show records where Start occurs in the next 24 hours. I tried something like this:

```
  @user_reminders  = user.reminders.where(["start >= ?", DateTime.now] && ["start <= ?", 1.day.from_now])
```

But it's returning incorrect results.

Users have many Reminders. Reminders belong to Users. All the associations are working fine, it's just returning results that are not within the date range. This is in a mailer if changes anything.

Cheers

Comment: Does that syntax work? I think you might be shooting yourself in the foot there.. Try `.where().where()` instead of the `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help explain what is going on

```
[1] pry(main)> [1] && [2]
=> [2]
```

So when you do

```
.where(["start >= ?", DateTime.now] && ["start <= ?", 1.day.from_now])
```

you end up doing

```
.where(["start <= ?", 1.day.from_now])
```

which might explain your issues.

Try

```
.where("start >= ?", DateTime.now).where("start <= ?", 1.day.from_now)
```

This works as you might want.

Answer (score 2):

That's the wrong syntax for chaining two `where` conditions together. The `&&` is evaluated immediately, resolves to the second operand, and only that gets passed through to `where`.

Any of these will work:

```
.where('start >= ?', DateTime.now).where('start <= ?', 1.day.from_now)
```

or

```
.where('start >= ? and start <= ?', DateTime.now, 1.day.from_now)
```

or, probably the best option,

```
.where(start: DateTime.now..1.day.from_now)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
 @user_reminders  = user.reminders.where(start: DateTime.now..1.day.from_now)
```